# Jni4Net with different JDK's

Tags: jni4net

I am building C# proxies for Java classes (using proxygen.xml) and my question is: can `Jni4Net` compile `.java` files using different JDK than saved in JAVA_HOME variable? Or do I need to change it temporary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jni4Net uses the JAVA_HOME path, so the easiest option in your case is to change it temporarily.

Comment: As an addition, on the target pc there is no need to install a JRE for jni4net. You can unzip it on an appropriate place and set `bridgeSetup.JavaHome = yourJrePath`